# Apache2 Ubuntu 500 Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4

```
[Sun Jul 05 10:19:53.611919 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4170:tid 140530536925056] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 05 10:19:53.612026 2015] [core:notice] [pid 4170:tid 140530536925056] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Jul 05 10:21:57.290092 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4170:tid 140530536925056] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jul 05 10:21:58.355151 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4412:tid 139991928010624] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 05 10:21:58.355253 2015] [core:notice] [pid 4412:tid 139991928010624] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Jul 05 10:37:37.221014 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4412:tid 139991928010624] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jul 05 10:37:38.236367 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 19041:tid 140166905907072] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 05 10:37:38.236487 2015] [core:notice] [pid 19041:tid 140166905907072] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Jul 05 10:53:52.505614 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 19041:tid 140166905907072] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

These are the last records on the log.
Page give me: 500 Internal Server Error.

I am deploying Flask app with digitalocean.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a 500 error response and nothing in the logs, does the error response look like a Flask generated error or the generic error page from Apache?

Likely it is from Flask, which is catching an exception and converting it to its own 500 error response page.

What you can do is temporarily enable Flask debug mode so it displays details of the error in the browser, or otherwise enable somehow Flask logging the details of the exception.

Without getting Flask to display somehow the details of the exception it is going to be impossible to guess what the problem is.